# How to read and write a file from a server in java?

Tags: java, file, server

I'm working on a project needing to fetch a file from a server as it would be for a local file. I need to be either able to read it and to write it On the server because I need to save content as data. until now this is what I've tried using an http server.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/testServer/hello.html");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        File f = new File(url.toURI());

        OutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(f);

        s.write("hello".getBytes());

        s.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but the logs says that

> uri scheme is not file

and I've tried other ways but none gone right.

Ps : don't know if it changes anything but it's an xml file I want to fetch.

Comment: Have you tried ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme . Not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: try this guide: https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010023

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413774/download-file-via-http-with-unknown-length-with-java

Comment: No it’s not a duplicate i’ve already gone through this answer but it doesn’t allows me to write the file on the server.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to write back to the html file being served up over HTTP.  You may be able to send a POST, PUT, etc. to a rest-like API end point to do it (or SOAP or ....), or you could download, modify local copy, and upload in code via (s)ftp(s), scp, webdav, etc.

Comment: ok how could I sent the whole data to an http endpoint so that the server writes it on the file ?